# What can affect the final build of a linux kernel

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel

I have a small problem.  I need to rebuild a version of linux so that it matches a version built a while ago.  But, I am having some problems.

I was wondering what aspects of a linux box would affect the build process of the kernel?  Here are a few facts.

At present our company uses a pre-built and pre-installed version of fedora to install engineers development box.  This version is just block copied onto blank hard disks.  If I use a development box I can successfully rebuild the kernel so it is a byte for byte match with the original that I am trying to reproduce.

But I need to prove to a government body that we have done nothing bad to the kernel, so they require us to build the linux kernel on a machine that has been installed from scratch using only trust software.  Trusted means downloaded from official web sites and verified via hashing results.  A machine built in this manner produces a kernel that differs from that built on the development box (and therefore differs from the original I am trying to match).

What variables may affect the outcome of the build?  At present these are the same across the two boxes (trusted and development)

- GCC version
- Run time kernel
- source of kernel I am trying to rebuild (including .configs files)

Any ideas on what create the differences?

Comment: To the person voting to close: How exactly is this 'not a real question'?

Comment: A perfectly acceptable question. Bit-identical reproducible builds is definitely programming related and very much a real question.

Comment: Please, edit the title to `affect`. It makes me cringe while reading the question.

Answer (score 2):

The linux kernel contains a number of timestamps and other non-deterministic elements. [This patch series](http://lwn.net/Articles/437864/) eliminates these, allowing for a deterministic build.